# Silex subform collections

Tags: symfony, twig, silex

I'm using Silex and trying to build a form with a set of fields that belong to a group.

Can something similiar to the code below be done? (My example currently doesnt yield any error, but nothing get's listed in Twig..)

**In my route:**

```
$builder = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form');

$tags[] = array('label' => 'Tag A', 'data' => 1);
$tags[] = array('label' => 'Tag B', 'data' => 2);

foreach($tags as $key => $tag) {
  $builder->add('tags', 'collection', array(
    'type'   => 'text',
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'options'  => array(
      'label' => $tag['label'],
      'constraints' => array(new Assert\NotBlank()),
      'data' => $tag['data']
    ),
  ));
}

$form = $builder->getForm();
```

**In Twig:**

```
<ul class="tags">
  {% for tag in form.tags %}
    <li>{{ form_row(tag) }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Silex for awhile but the principles should be the same as Symfony.

You shouldn't be creating the collection in a loop like that. You're basically creating multiple collections for each tag. Instead you want a single collection for all tags. I didn't test this but something along these lines should work ...

```php
// form variables ...
$tags[] = array('label' => 'Tag A', 'data' => 1);
$tags[] = array('label' => 'Tag B', 'data' => 2);
$data = array( 'tags' => $tags );

$builder = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form', $data);
$builder->add('tags', 'collection', array(
    'type'   => 'text',
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'options'  => array(
        'constraints' => array(new Assert\NotBlank()),
    ),
));
```